How to set the text of a mat-select control
In this app here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-6b7grk?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts
Is it possible to make it so that I can programmatically set the value of the mat-select's text control?
For example, right now, if the user clicks on "one" then the control's text will become "one". Another example, if they click on "one" and "two" then the control's text will be "one, two".
Can I make it so that, as an example, I could display "1" in the first case, and "1,2" in the second?

I hope it makes your requirements work:
select-preview-example.component.ts


import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild('drop') dropControl: any;

  // public to template
  isOpen = false;
  allNums /** all numbers */ = [
    {
      ui: 'one',
      logic: 1,
    },
    {
      ui: 'two',
      logic: 2,
    },
  ];

  isOpening(isOpen: boolean) {
    this.isOpen = isOpen;
  }

}



select-preview-example.component.html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    (openedChange)="isOpening($event)"
    #drop
    placeholder="Select numbers"
    multiple
  >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let num of allNums;">
      {{isOpen ? num.ui : num.logic}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


This answers the question which I posed perfectly. Thank you very much. My mistake was to think that the answer to this question would enable me to then work out the answer to the problem I had. That was my mistake as my problem is slightly different. I have posted another question to address this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78704154/how-to-implement-a-certain-behavior-with-mat-select

No problem, i just posted an answer and hope that you get the idea. I found the  selector does this work out of the box without triggering any output to check if it open!
