How to implement a certain behavior with mat-select
I have a stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-uxtev9?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html,app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts
How can this be changed so that if the user selects the "all" option, then all of the checkboxes become checked AND the text of the mat-select then just says "all". Similarly if the user clicks all checkboxes except the "all" option then the "all" option should become checked and, again, the text of the mat-option should say "all".
Thanks for any help.

Another one that not depending of you have a [(ngModel)] or FormControl
We can get the options using ViewChildren and I choose separate the options in array and selectAll
@ViewChildren(MatOption) options: QueryList<MatOption>;
allNums: string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

Our HTML
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select 
    #drop
    placeholder="Select numbers"
    multiple
  >
  <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="drop.value && drop.value.length">
    {{drop.value.length>allNums.length?'All':
      drop.value[0]===null?drop.value.slice(1):
      drop.value}}
  </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option #all (click)="onClick(all)" [value]="null">Select all</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let num of allNums" [value]="num" (click)="onClick()">
      {{num}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

And the function "onClick"
  onClick(el: any = null) {
    if (el == this.options.first) {
      this.options.forEach((x) => {
        x[el.selected ? 'select' : 'deselect']();
      });
    } else {
      const selected = this.options.filter((x, index) => index && x.selected);
      if (selected.length == this.allNums.length) this.options.first.select();
      if (selected.length == 0) this.options.first.deselect();
    }
  }

stackblitz
Update Suggest by gnisut, we can pass to the function "click" the options (and we needn't use the ViewChild). I change the function and the arguments to show. So the .html becomes like
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value"
    #drop
    placeholder="Select numbers"
    multiple
  >
  <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="drop.value && drop.value.length">
    {{drop.value.length>allNums.length?'All':
      drop.value[0]===null?drop.value.slice(1):
      drop.value}}
  </mat-select-trigger>
    <!--see that we pass "drop.options" and "true"-->
    <mat-option (click)="onClick(drop.options,true)" [value]="null">Select all</mat-option>

    <!--see that we pass "drop.options"-->
    <mat-option *ngFor="let num of allNums" [value]="num" (click)="onClick(drop.options)">
      {{num}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

And the function onClick very "similar" to before:
  onClick(options:QueryList<MatOption>,isFirst:boolean=false) {
    if (isFirst) {
      const el=options.first;
      options.forEach((x) => {
        x[el.selected ? 'select' : 'deselect']();
      });
    } else {
      const selected = options.filter((x, index) => index && x.selected);
      if (selected.length == this.allNums.length) options.first.select();
      if (selected.length == 0) options.first.deselect();
    }
  }


Thanks very much for this, very much appreciated. Would it be possible to modify it so that the onClick function could be made "self-contained" by having it accept as an additional argument the variable which is currently stored in this.options? So that there would be no need to have @ViewChildren(MatOption) options: QueryList; in the ts file as we would be passing the list of MatOption objects as an argument to the onClick function when it is called in the html code.

@gnitsuk, sure!. As we have a template reference "#drop" to the mat-select, and a matSelect has a property: "options" (you can see in github you can pass to the function onClick(drop.options). I just update the answer and the stackblitz with your idea.

Great, yes I just tried it and is all working fine. Thanks very much for your answer and time and thanks very much too to all the other people who replied to help me. I've learned a lot from all of your help.

(I've added a further question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78706735/how-to-bind-the-check-properties-of-a-mat-select

I hope that shows All Users with easiest way:
There are other use cases to handle but i think you will get the idea.
select-overview-example.component.ts


import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  // form
  usersCtrl = new FormControl([]);

  // public to template
  users: User[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'stack',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'over',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'flow',
    },
  ];

  // helper
  private isAllSelect = false;

  selectedUsers() {
    return this.usersCtrl.value.length == this.users.length + 1 // add 1 coz the first option is just a helper
      ? 'All Users'
      : this.usersCtrl.value;
  }

  selectAllState() {
    if (this.isAllSelect) {
      this.usersCtrl.patchValue([]);
    } else {
      this.usersCtrl.patchValue(this.getIds());
    }
    this.isAllSelect = !this.isAllSelect;
  }

  selectedOption(id: number) {
    // log one id
    console.log(id);

    /**
     * Here you can add the business logic for other use cases:
     *
     *
     * 1- If all selected without fist option, the first option then should be added
     * 2- If all options are true but one option de-selected, the first option should de-selected too.
     */
  }

  submitToServer() {
    // dont forget to exclude the first option if all selected
  }

  private getIds() {
    return [...this.users.map((user) => user.id), 0];
  }
}



select-overview-example.component.html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [formControl]="usersCtrl" placeholder="Users" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger *ngIf="this.usersCtrl.value.length > 0">
      {{selectedUsers()}}
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option (click)="selectAllState()" [value]="0"> {{'All'}} </mat-option>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let user of users;"
      [value]="user.id"
      (click)="selectedOption(user.id)"
    >
      {{user.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

To avoid any error with multiple select, the FormControl should always have an array as value.

Here is a solution for you:
    //HTML
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select
        #drop
        (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)"
        placeholder="Select numbers"
        multiple
        [(value)]="selected"
      >
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let num of allNums"
          [value]="num"
          (click)="onClick(num)"
        >
          {{ num }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>


    //TS
    import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
    
    /**
     * @title Mat-Select Multiple initialisation with ngModel
     */
    @Component({
      selector: 'select-overview-example',
      templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
    })
    export class SelectOverviewExample {
      @ViewChild('drop') dropControl: any;
    
      allNums: string[] = ['all', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
      selected: string[] = [];
    
      onClick(value: string) {
        if (value === 'all') {
          if (this.selected.length + 1 === this.allNums.length) {
            this.selected = [];
          } else {
            this.selected = this.allNums;
          }
        }
      }
    
      doSomething(e: any) {
        // console.log(e);
      }
    }


If you need additional help, let me know.

Here is the solution for your problem, I hope this will get your work done with minimal changes please let me know if this fulfil your requirements. Thanks


import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSelectChange } from '@angular/material';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  modules = [
    { value: 'module1', viewValue: 'Module 1' },
    { value: 'module2', viewValue: 'Module 2' },
  ];
  selected: string[] = [];

  onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
    if (event.value.includes('all')) {
      event.value = ['all'];
      this.selected = ['all'];
    }
    console.log('Event', event.value, this.selected);

    // const allIndex = event.value.indexOf('all');
    // if (allIndex > -1 && this.allAlreadySelected == false)
    //   {
    //     //if all is selected, select all browsers
    //     this.selectedModules = ['all', ...this.modules.map(b => b.value)];
    //     this.allAlreadySelected = !this.allAlreadySelected;
    //   }
    // else if (allIndex > -1 && this.allAlreadySelected) {
    //   this.selectedModules = [];
    //   this.allAlreadySelected = !this.allAlreadySelected;
    // }
  }
}
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select
    placeholder="Select Modules"
    multiple
    [(ngModel)]="selected"
    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
  >
    <mat-option [value]="'all'">All</mat-option>
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let module of modules"
      [value]="module.value"
      [disabled]="selected.includes('all')"
      >{{module.viewValue}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Yes sure i have just started answering on community as i progress everyday i will improve my self with explanation thanks a lot for the suggestion.
