How to bind the check properties of a mat-select
In this stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-multi-with-formcontrol-nfsokg?file=app%2Fselect-overview-example.html,app%2Fselect-overview-example.ts
The default settings of the check boxes for the entries "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" in the drop down are false, so all boxes are unchecked.
How can I two-way-data-bind these values to the variable "checks" in the ts file?:
checks: boolean[] = [true, true, false, false, true];

A mat-select multiple, when binding the variable is a string with the values selecteds.
You can filter the array "allNums" in the way only the "checkes"
  allNums: string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  checks: boolean[] = [true, true, false, false, true];
  value:string[]= this.getValues(this.allNums,checks)

getValues(allNumns:string[],checks:boolean[])
{
    return allNumns.filter((x,index)=>checks[index]);
}

Rememeber that filter method of an array, like find, map, forEach, reduce, etc have an aditional argument that it's the "index"
NOTE: To return an array of true/false you can do using map
const checks=this.allNums.map(x=>value.indexOf(x)>=0)

